# How can I run git bash scripts from any folder (Running Windows 7)

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have a folder for my `.bat` and `.sh` files.
This folder is part of my `PATH`. I can run the `.bat` files without any problems using the command prompt. But I can't run the `.sh` files with git bash.
I have made the scripts executable, and if I'm in the folder where the scripts are then I can run them with `./myScript.sh` for example, without any trouble.
If I echo the `PATH` variable I git bash shows that the scripts folder is included.
If I run `which myScript.sh` I get `/c/opt/scripts/myScript.sh`
So what am I missing?

Also, I'd really like to run it with just `myScript` instead of `./myScript.sh` is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `.bashrc` file. In my case it was in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc` and it was actually called `bash.bashrc`

In the bottom of that file I added the following:

`alias myScript=\'/c/opt/scripts/./myScript.sh\'`

This solved both my issues. I can now run the script from anywhere simply by typing `myScript`

Comment: just in case if you do not know: the reason of such behavior is securuty, so writing  ./  prefix  is really saying "yes, I want to run it, please first look up in current folder", so suppressing a search in PATH.